# One Apple ID being used for multiple phones. How to create a new Apple ID for one?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, apple-id, sharing

I have a question regarding using the same Apple ID for multiple phones. I have let my dad use my Apple ID to purchase apps and stuff, and now I realize that he uses my ID for iCloud, and all our photos and everything are instantly shared on both of our phones. Can someone please help to walk me through the process of setting up a new Apple ID? Or do I have to go see one of the tech guys in Apple store for this matter?
Thank you!

Comment: There are two paths to your goal, complicated a little by what account you want to use for App Store on both devices. Will the new iCloud account also be an App Store account or do you need to use an old / pre-existing App Store account but set up a new iCloud for email, etc...

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to http://appleid.apple.com and grab a new Apple ID.
2. Open the Settings.app on your dad's iPhone.
3. Select "iCloud" and scroll to the bottom of the page.
4. Select "Delete Account".

   Don't worry, this won't delete the actual Apple ID account, it will just remove it from the phone.
5. Now login to the new Apple ID.

Comment: with this delete the current pictures and contacts on the phone also? or no?

Comment: @DanteFeliciano, first, I will note that those steps won't *delete* anything, but it may remove it from your phone. For contacts, if you have them synced to iCloud, you can choose to keep them on your phone or to remove them from your phone. This is the case with calendars, reminders, etc. I am not sure whether it would remove Photostream pictures or not. Does that answer your question?